# C++ Is endianness affecting fstream's read and write functions?

Tags: c++, filestream, endianness

I am learning how to write to/read from binary files, and I want my files to be readable for any machine that supports C++ 17. So I had an horrifying thought: what if read() and write() are affected by the endianness of the machine?

For exemple:
I run this code on a big endian machine,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdint>

int main() {

    std::ofstream Output("Hey.txt", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::binary);

    if (Output.is_open()) {
        int16_t i = 42;
        Output.write((const char*)&i, 2);
    }

}
```

Then I pass Hey.txt to a small endian machine, then run this code on the machine,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdint>

int main() {

std::ifstream Input("Hey.txt", std::ifstream::in | std::ifstream::binary);

    if (Input.is_open()) {
        int16_t i;
        Input.read((char*)&i, 2);
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }

}
```

Will the program print 42? Or is fstream handling the endian difference? If not, is there a way to prevent endian issues?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: It just read bytes, nothing more. You're the one reinterpreting those bytes as integers, so you're the one who has to deal with endianness conversions.

Comment: endianness affects the way you write a big entity into memory. There are only a stream of bytes here so endianness is irrelevant

Comment: When you do it that way, yes endian of the platform affect what you read/write.  Don't do it that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two simple rules:

1. If you're going to write binary data to a file, document the file format.
2. When you write binary data to a file, make sure the bytes you are writing match the requirements of the file format.

If the file format says that there's a 16-bit integer in big-endian format, and you write code that reads or writes that, everything will work fine.

Don't use a cast like this `(char*)&i` because then the bytes will hold whatever format the native system happens to use for 16-bit integers and that is not even guaranteed (by the C++ standard) to be stable across runs of the same code on the same system.

Comment: So, If I read a file extension that says "there's a 16-bit int in big-endian format" on a little-endian machine, I have to swap the bytes myself? Also, how can I cast my references to a char pointer without (char*), nor the C++ reinterpreted cast?

Comment: Well, I found a great article that explained what you said, I now I understand the concept.http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/DzywvCM9/